# Scalatest to check if a map contains values form a list

Tags: scala, scalatest

A method is returning a `Map` of tuples, for this test to pass I need to check that the map contains `n` number of keys and that the key values match.

I started with a `result.foreach(f=> f._ == "value"))` but I can't seem to check the other values in the same loop.

Comment: What are the types for the keys and values?

Comment: @Vidya they're both strings, keys are unique

Comment: Can you give an example of the Map and the List as well as what you want to get from them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Map defined below:

```
val test = Map( ("a","aa") -> false, ("b","bb") -> false, ("c","cc") -> true)
```

You could do something like:

`test.map {
  foo => val ((tupleKey,tupleValue),value) = foo
    // you could add your checking of key value here
    (tupleKey,tupleValue,value)
}`

In code snippet above, I am using variable names to access tuple elements. I am returning a tuple so what should be returned is:

`res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, String, Boolean)] = List((a,aa,false), (b,bb,false), (c,cc,true))`

As you can see above you can access `tupleKey` , `tupleValue` and `value` that you wanted to access. I have used Strings and Boolean for simplicity but you can easily use the above example for your usecase as well. Regarding checking map test you could add `test.size mustEqual expectedSize` where `expectedSize` is a `val` which is the size of the collection you expect.

Let me know if you need more clarification. I am glad to help.